# Why has this user's reputation removed/deleted?

Tags: discussion, bug

*Note: I have nothing against this user. I am just trying to shed some light on this issue.*

---

User [@One-Eye-Triangle's](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/91865/one-eye-triangle?tab=topactivity) reputation has dropped down to 1. This change occurred after he/she has posted [two answers to this question which got deleted due to it being spams.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134870/why-are-p%E2%88%92f-bond-lengths-in-phosphorus-pentafluoride-the-same) Each answer got -4 downvotes before getting deleted and these downvotes point should affect his/her total rep. points[final rep = initial rep - 16] and when the community bots deleted those answers, the rep. points went all the way down to 1. Is it some sort of glitch? Or is it a punishment? If it is a punishment, then his/her profile should reflect the [suspension notice where the rep. gets locked at 1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). But that didn't happen in this case. Where did the rep. points go? Here is the screenshot of the user's reputation graph:

[image]

The graph seems incomplete. It is not showing the downfall from ~200 rep to 1. What happened here?

Comment: "6 red flags: the post is locked and deleted, and the author loses 100 reputation." https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/spam-rude-and-abusive-flags

Comment: *Flags @Ortho's comment as a comment–answer*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [Help Centre](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation),

> You lose reputation when:
>
> - your question is voted down: −2
> - your answer is voted down: −2
> - you vote down an answer: −1
> - you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
> - one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100